# FatalExecutionEngineError was detected at byte[] allocation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, arrays, fatal-error

I had a code which was working fine. Suddenly it started giving fatal error at one location. The error msg is below. 
It occurs are a byte[] allocation.

```
byte[] b = new byte[69+(data.Length*4)];
```

where Length = 1078400. (For smaller size,the code runs normal).

> FatalExecutionEngineError was detected Message: The runtime has
>   encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x5e53a1f9,
>   on thread 0x11d8. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a
>   bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user
>   code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for
>   COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

EDIT: More code:

> public WriteFocFile(List fochead, cuFloatComplex[] data,>
>   string path)
>
> ```
>      {
>         double[] a = new double[fochead.Count];
>         a = fochead.ToArray();
>         double datares = (a[6] - a[5]) / (Math.Pow(2,a[3]));
>
>         byte[] b = new byte[69+(data.Length*4)];
>
>         b[0] = Convert.ToByte(a[0]);
>
>         b[1] = Convert.ToByte(a[1]);
>         b[2] = Convert.ToByte(a[2]);
>         b[3] = Convert.ToByte(a[3]);
>         Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToUInt16(a[4])), 0, b, 4, 2);
>         //similarly more Buffer.BlockCopy
>
>         cuFloatComplex temp;
>         for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
>         {
>            //array operation and copying of data in b
>         }
>         File.WriteAllBytes(@path+".msf", b);
>
>     }
> ```

Comment: Do you have unmanaged code? Do you use external librairies? Did you update any of those recently?

Comment: i dont use unmanaged code directly. i only used wrapped dlls which are added as references.

Comment: I think we need some context here (include more code, like where `data` is coming from).

Comment: The most obvious thing is to double-check the value of ``data.Length`` and make sure it's not some ridiculously large number. Other than that, does your machine have the latest Windows Updates?

Comment: its updated. and length is about 4 MB, should not be an issue.

Comment: The error likely comes from these wrapped dlls. Have you changed them recently?

Comment: actually no. in first run, code passed this point and i had a bug later. i fixed bug (which was simple indexing issue), i run code again and i got this error. for this part of code, i dont use anything dll. its simple byte array that i am creating from a list, and writing it to a file.

Comment: Stop staring at that line of code, it isn't the cause.  It merely is likely to trigger a garbage collection.  Which crashed because *other* code that ran earlier has corrupted the GC heap.  With those "wrapped dlls", whatever that means, being a likely source of the damage.

Comment: @HansPassant ok. anyways to debug the code? i got lots of large arrays, and i set them to null once i dont need them anymore. i take GC will reclaim the memory which was used by the array.

Comment: This error usually indicates a heap corruption. There is no point looking at your managed code. The damage is done earlier by unmanaged code.

Comment: thanks for the tips.. i will go into unmanaged code.. will update here once i find something

Comment: ya.. 2 byte were not being freed in unmanged code.. works now. thanks people

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by unmanaged part of the code somewhere else. Most likely the unmanaged  code was corrupting the managed heap which resulted into FatalExecutionEngineError. To be specific, the error was caused by an unmanaged array which was not handled properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: its my question, and based on comments, i found my problem. the problem in itself is irreverent to this question.

Comment: @Naresh Even if this is your own question aswwer should say something reasonable. This was marked low quality by an automatic mechanism.

Comment: It seems that it matters to me.